# Can I deploy two wso2 api manager in same cluster

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I like to installing wso2 api manager in a cluster.Is it possible to create two api manager server in same cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure 2 API Manager nodes in Active-Active. Both starts accepting traffic routing, API creation, etc.

Please refer -

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/single-node/configuring-an-active-active-deployment/#configuring-an-active-active-deployment